# How to make equivalent system using the Noble Identity?

Tags: linear-systems

I am trying to get equivalent of this system using the Noble Identities:

$$x[n] \rightarrow \boxed{H(z^L)} \rightarrow \boxed{\uparrow L} \rightarrow y[n]$$

my answer is

$$x[n] \rightarrow \boxed{\uparrow L}  \rightarrow \boxed{H(z^{L\cdot L})} \rightarrow y[n]$$

Is this answer correct?

Comment: Yes, this is a correct answer.